# Как обработать ошибку nanogallery2: error: no media to process. и закрыть галерею, когда она появляется?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Решил для своего форума использовать nanogallery2. В моем случае, галерея постоянно вызывается, даже когда в посте нет изображений. В доке не нашел, как закрыть ее при такой ошибке, но в консоль выводится данная ошибка, когда в галерее нет файлов.

Comment: Правте вопрос с учётки, с котрой вы его создали.

Comment: А при чем тут метки HTML и CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде нашел ответ, но не знаю, на сколько это правильно.
Вместо сообщения о выводе ошибки я вставил следующий код, который прячет пустую галлерею
document.getElementById(G.baseEltID).style.display='none';